# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity) in angular 7

Tags: angular

I am getting error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity) in my angular 7 application while binding the data to the html table

Please find the stackblitz here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nqpv4x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: That's an error from the server, the only error I see on the blitz is `isInvestedSelected is not a function.`

Comment: i commented out that bit as it is not needed but still getting the error

Comment: My point was this isn't an Angular issue.  The server is returning the error, it's right there in the error message :)

Comment: The code in is angular and data is hardcoded in the client. If it isn’t angular

Comment: The stackblitz doesn't reproduce the error either.

Comment: Can somebody tell me how do i hook this data to populate the table?